# Active or Disabled action button in a mobile form?

Tags: forms, buttons

I have a "change password" screen where the user's password has expired and he/she has to change it. it's a standard screen with "New password" and "Re-type new password" fields, with an inline validation that checks whether the password guidelines are met (while the user is typing): 8 characters, 1 digit, 1 number, 1 special character.

we have an argument whether the main "change password" action button should be disabled until all the validations are clear, or to keep it active and provide an error message if needed.

what do you think is better?

Answer (score 1):

Both are good. But keeping the button active and providing an error message pointing to the error made is better.

This way the user also knows what is keeping them from changing the password when the error message pops.

Answer (score 0):

If you have inline validation for string password and password be same, It's OK to disable button until fields are valid. But if you haven't done that, it's good to not disable CTA button. Good luck!